# N Queen recursive program

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic

I am trying to solve the n-queen problem (placing n queens on a nxn board without any two queens attacking each other) by defining a function that takes an nxn boolean array of falses and should fill the answer with true where the queens should be. I am getting incorrect answer but can't see why the recursion doesn't work!

```
bool check(bool ** board, int n, int row, int col){
  if(row == 0) return true;
  for(int r = 0 ; r < row ; ++r){
    if(board[r][col]) return false;
    int left = max(col - row + r, 0), right = min(col + row - r, n-1);
    if(board[r][left] || board[r][right]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}


bool queen(bool ** board, int n, int level = 0 ){
  for(int col = 0 ; col < n ; ++col){
    if( !check(board, n, level, col) ) continue;
    board[ level ][ col ] = true;
    if( level == n-1 ) return true;
    if( queen(board, n, level+1) ) return true;
    board[ level ][ col ] = false;
  }
  return false;
}
```

in main() i dynamically create bool ** board, and fill it with false, then call queen(board, n).

The weird thing is that it is giving the correct solution except for n=4,6!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fault is the min/max.Operation, so you don't check straight lines.
This should do the trick:

```
int left = col - row + r;
int right = col + row - r;

    if ( left >= 0 && board[r][left] || right < n && board[r][right])
            return false;
```

Comment: thanks this actually works now! but I don't understand what's the problem with min max, since they only ensure I don't leave the boundaries of the board and do the same job as your conditional statement

Comment: when you reach the edge of the board, your running down the column: starting with [1,3], you check [0,2], then [0,1] and [0,0]. Thats what i meant with not checking straight lines...